# sort table view titanium android

Tags: javascript, android, sorting, titanium, tableview

I am trying to sort a json feed before inserting it into a table view.  I have a method that works fine on iOS however when I try to implement the same code on android it will only sort once.

I need to have the data sorted at least twice for the application.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('get.stands', function(d) {

        jsonArray = JSON.parse(d.responseText);

        var hockey = jsonArray;

        //alert('Hockey Standings');
        //Ti.API.info('My data is..' + hockey);


        function sortBy(prop) {
            return function(a, b) {
                if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            //hockey.sort(sortBy('conference'));
            //hockey.sort(sortBy('points'));
        }

        var data = [];


        hockey.sort(sortBy('points'));
        hockey.sort(sortBy('division'));
        hockey.sort(sortBy('conterence'));
        //myPoints.sort(function(a,b){return a - b;});
        var addRow = function(obj) {
            var teamPoint = parseInt(obj.points);
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                backgroundColor : '#fff',
                //hasChild : true,
                height : '50dp',
                width : Ti.UI.SIZE
            });

            var myTeam = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                color : '#000',
                font : {
                    fontSize : 16,
                    fontWeight : 'bold'
                },
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                highlightedColor : '#fff',
                left : '55dp',
                top : '0dp',
                text : obj.team,
                width : Ti.UI.SIZE
            });

            var teamPoints = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                color : '#666',
                font : {
                    fontSize : 14
                },
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                highlightedColor : '#ddd',
                left : '55dp',
                top : '20dp',
                text : 'Points: ' + teamPoint.toFixed(0),
                //top: 5,
                width : Ti.UI.SIZE
            });

            var teamImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    image : 'http://www.corliosity.com/json/' + obj.img,
                    left : '0dp',
                    top : '0dp',
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50
            });
                if (obj.conference)
                {
                    row.add(myTeam);
                }
                if (obj.team)
                {
                    row.add(myTeam);
                    row.add(teamPoints);
                    row.add(teamImage); 
                }
            return row;
        };
        var intItem = 0, intItems = hockey.length, strLastDivision = '', row;

        for ( intItem = 0; intItem < intItems; intItem = intItem + 1) {
            var bgcolor = (intItem % 2) ? '#fff' : "#ccc";


            row = addRow(hockey[intItem]);
            if (strLastDivision !== hockey[intItem].division) {
                strLastDivision = hockey[intItem].division;
                row.header = hockey[intItem].division;
            }

            data.push(row);
            row.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);
        };

        var tbl = Ti.UI.createTableView({
            data : data,
            height : Ti.UI.FILL,
            //minRowHeight: 80,
            //search: search,
            //style : Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
            width : Ti.UI.FILL
        });

        win.add(tbl);

    });
```

And the JSON code will look like this

```
[{"team":"team1", "points":"18", "division":"west","conference":"west"}, {"team":"team2","points":"23","division":"south","conference":"east"}]
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: why you need to sort twice. from your code i see that you call `sort` 3 times but i don't see where you want to sort twice?

Comment: Ideally I would like to sort the data three times but I must have the data sort at the very least by points and by division.  Unfortunately the code will only run one of the sort functions.

Comment: did you try to debug this via emulator? maybe you need to use `hockey = hockey.sort(sortBy('...'));` each time...

Comment: I have been running it on a device (mainly because the emulator is too buggy for me).  Unfortunately trying to set `hockey = hockey.sort(sortBy('...'));` merits the same result with only the last  sort function being displayed.

Comment: well usually `hockey = hockey.sort(sortBy('...'));` should be wrong. it was simply an idea. With Titanium 3.0.0 you can debug also on device. Did you try that? First i would try to ensure, that really each function is executed (regardless their results) and after that i would try to examine the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"team":"team1", "points":"18", "division":"west","conference":"west"}, {"team":"team2","points":"23","division":"south","conference":"east"}]
```

If this is the real JSON response it seems that your numbers are delivered as strings. If this is right you should ensure, that numbers are compared (i'm not that familiar with JS translation of Titanium for Android and maybe Titanium is trying to compare strings. JS behavior is sometimes different on iOS and Android). See the `parseInt` or `parseFloat` functions. [Here are some examples](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm).

```
function sortBy(prop) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (parseInt(a[prop]) > parseInt(b[prop])) {
            return -1;
        } else if (parseInt(a[prop]) < parseInt(b[prop])) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running all the data through that function.  I tried using a parseInt and then return the greater number however it yielded the same results.

Comment: Then you can only try to debug the functions. Put in some log statements there and monitor it with logcat if you run it on device.